# Google Play Android Developer API 401 Insufficient permissions

Tags: node.js, google-play-services, google-oauth

I'm using [Google Play Android Developer API](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/index) to server to server check subscription status of our users' subscriptions but after successful authorization and asking for an existing subscription I get the 401 response with the following message 'The current user has insufficient permissions to perform the requsted operation'. 
Visiting https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=XXXXXX I can see that I do have the requested scope (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher) but I still get the same response everytime. 
Did anyone else have the same problem?

Edit: I've seen what the Explore API app does, it adds the key in the query string of a request but I don't have that value. In the console I've created a Service Account Client Id which has a client id, email address and a private key but there is no API key which apparently Explore API uses.

Edit no. 2: I've added the service account generated email both to Google Play Developer Console and Google Wallet console but I still have no acces. I'm using nodejs and the [google-oauth-jwt](https://www.npmjs.org/package/google-oauth-jwt) because there is not google provided lib for nodejs.

Here is the code I'm using to make a request:

```
var request = require('google-oauth-jwt').requestWithJWT();

function makeReq() {
    request({
        url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v1.1/applications/{packageName}/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/purchases/{purchaseToken}',
        jwt: {
            // use the email address of the service account, as seen in the API console
            email: 'blahblahtrutjtrutj@developer.gserviceaccount.com',
            // use the PEM file we generated from the downloaded key
            keyFile: 'purchases-test.pem',
            // specify the scopes you wish to access
            scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher']
        }
    }, function (err, res, body) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log("BODY IS ------------------------------------------");
            console.log(JSON.parse(body));
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: scroll down a bit look for "Public API access"  try and use that

Comment: @DaImTo, did you mean to use both Public API access together with OAuth Service account or without it? And, besides, I've read [this](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount) a couple of times already and there is no mention of key to pass to API when making calls

Comment: You did give the service account access to the play account?  Note:  I know service accounts have little or no android play experience :)

Comment: And how do I do that? :) I've went to the [console](https://console.developers.google.com) and under APIs & auth - Credentials added new Client ID which is Service Account. I don't know what else to do.

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54591/google-apis  come chat :)

Answer (score 8):

If your app is only released in a closed alpha track, you'll also have to add your service account's email address (client_email) to the License Testers at Settings -> Account detail in the Play Console.

Answer (score 2):

There is an email address associated with your service account.

This needs to have appropriate permissions in both the dev console AND the Play store. Make sure to add the service address to the Play store.

The way I approached it was to use

```
var googleAuth = require('google-oauth-jwt'),
    authObject = {
        email: 'blahblahtrutjtrutj@developer.gserviceaccount.com',
        keyFile: 'purchases-test.pem',
        scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher']
    };

googleAuth.authenticate(authObject, function (err, token) {
    next(err, token);
});
```

I store the token in redis for an hour and use that token to make my request to the store:

```
var opts = {
    url : verifyUrl + payload.packageName + '/inapp/' + payload.productId + '/purchases/' + payload.token,
    headers: {
        authorization : 'Bearer ' + token
    }
};

request.get(opts, function (error, response, body) {
    next(error, response, body);
});
```

Comment: I did that and even after one day I didn't have access to the API.

Comment: The change was automatic for me. Updated to include my process. I don't use the requestWithJWT, I use the actual request npm module.

Comment: this worked for me too, once I had linked my API project in the playstore dev console settings

Comment: I had this account added in the play store but it had read only permissions. It looks like the account must have the '
View financial reports' permission ?!?!

Comment: That account needs admin permissions.

Answer (score 0):

If you're certain that you have granted the adequate permissions, try deactivating and activating a product... It might sound stupid but it did work for me after wasting a lot of time